# How can I use label_dollar to represent a number 60000 in 60K?

Tags: r, label

When I use this function below:

```
scale_x_continuous(labels = label_dollar())
```

the graph shows like:

[image]

However, I use this function:

```
scale_x_continuous(labels = label_number_si(prefix = "$"))
```

in order to represent the number like this:

[image]

Can I use the first function to get the second result?

Comment: Did you try? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the `scale` and `suffix` arguments to achieve this.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10000,20000,30000,40000),
                 y = 1:4)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::label_dollar(scale = .001,
                                                   suffix = "K"))
```